# Access select latest entry of unique identifier

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access table with multiple date entries for each unique identifier

```
Year      ID  TotalSpent
2003-2004 001 1000
2002-2003 001  900
2001-2002 001  100
2009-2010 002 8000
2008-2009 002 4000
2000-2001 003  100
1999-2000 003    0
```

I want to keep the latest (top) entry for each unique ID to produce

```
Year      ID  TotalSpent
2003-2004 001 1000
2009-2010 002 8000
2000-2001 003  100
```

I have looked at the top() function but cannot get it to produce more than 1 result (as opposed to 1 result for each unique ID). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you did have a unique identifier. Is there ab autonumber id on that table by any chance or only multiple ID lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Year` and `ID` values you want with this query:

```sql
SELECT ID, Max([Year]) AS MaxOfYear
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Then to get the corresponding `TotalSpent` values, use that SQL for a subquery which you join to `YourTable`.

```sql
SELECT y.Year, y.ID, y.TotalSpent
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, Max([Year]) AS MaxOfYear
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY ID
        ) AS sub
    ON
            (y.Year = sub.MaxOfYear)
        AND (y.ID = sub.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remou makes a valid point that a unique ID would be beneficial as it would allow to refer to the top row in the future but this could be a constraint outside of your control.

The data source is a bit awkward with the hyphenated years which prevents a simple grouping query. The second issue is that you simply cannot just group by the max of the `TotalSpent` field as it may not be the last field (A large refund for instance may affect a years total).

My solution involves finding the latest Year for each ID (Query A) and then reforms the year-tag to join onto table B. I didn't want to perform a join on a calculated field so I have wrapped it in another subquery (Query B). This is then joined onto the original table/query to extract the key rows and values.

```
SELECT YourTable.[YourYearField],
   YourTable.ID,
   YourTable.TotalSpent
FROM   (SELECT A.ID,
           [StartYear] & "-" & [EndYear] AS Grouping
    FROM   (SELECT YourTable.ID,
                   Max(Val(Right$([YourYearField], 4)))     AS EndYear,
                   Max(Val(Right$([YourYearField], 4)) - 1) AS StartYear
            FROM   YourTable
            GROUP  BY YourTable.ID) AS A
    GROUP  BY A.ID,
              [StartYear] & "-" & [EndYear]) AS B
   INNER JOIN YourTable
           ON ( B.Grouping = YourTable.[YourYearField] )
              AND ( B.ID = YourTable.ID )
GROUP  BY YourTable.[YourYearField],
      YourTable.ID,
      YourTable.TotalSpent;
```